# How is this anonymous function being called

Tags: javascript

I came across this code:

```js
export default async function (req, res) {
 ...
}
```

This appears to be an anonymous function and it does get called when the app is run, but but I don't know how it can get called.

NOTE: This is part of a Nodejs app.

The entire code that it is part of is located in a single file:

```js
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export default async function (req, res) {
  if (!configuration.apiKey) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: {
        message: "OpenAI API key not configured, please follow instructions in README.md",
      }
    });
    return;
  }

  const animal = req.body.animal || '';
  if (animal.trim().length === 0) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: {
        message: "Please enter a valid animal",
      }
    });
    return;
  }

  try {
    const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "text-davinci-003",
      prompt: generatePrompt(animal),
      temperature: 0.6,
    });
    res.status(200).json({ result: completion.data.choices[0].text });
  } catch(error) {
    // Consider adjusting the error handling logic for your use case
    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.status, error.response.data);
      res.status(error.response.status).json(error.response.data);
    } else {
      console.error(`Error with OpenAI API request: ${error.message}`);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: {
          message: 'An error occurred during your request.',
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

function generatePrompt(animal) {
  const capitalizedAnimal =
    animal[0].toUpperCase() + animal.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  return `Suggest three names for an animal that is a superhero.

Animal: Cat
Names: Captain Sharpclaw, Agent Fluffball, The Incredible Feline
Animal: Dog
Names: Ruff the Protector, Wonder Canine, Sir Barks-a-Lot
Animal: ${capitalizedAnimal}
Names:`;
}
```

Comment: Some other file imports it.

Comment: What framework are you using? Consult its documentation. This is likely handled by the framework.

Comment: It's sample code from OpenAI. Even if it's imported, how is the function actually called?

Comment: What do you mean by `how`? Its called like any other function. Seems to be a http request handler function, so its probably called with an HTTPRequest object and a HTTPResponse object.

Comment: Normal functions have names, and you call them by using their name. But this function is anonymous and has no name. So how does it get called?

Comment: It gets a name when it is [imported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: I updated my post. The code is just part of a larger amount of code in the file which includes stuff outside of the function. So importing it cannot assign a name to just that function since other code is present.

Comment: `So importing it cannot assign a name to just that function since other code is present.` _Other code_ doesn't matter. Its `export default` so if you import the default you get __exactly__ that function, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#default_import) of a file. So when it is imported in another file, the whole default export can be placed into a variable.

```js
// file1.js
export default async function (req, res) {
 ...
}

// file2.js
import myDefault from "file1.js";

// do something with myDefault
```

Or using the alternative syntax, useful when there are other exports from the file:

```
// file3.js
import { default as alias } from "file1.js";

// do something with alias
```

Comment: I scanned the project but couldn't find anything that has "import { default". This is running in Nodejs. Maybe there is some other mechanism that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Function in question is an default export of the file, so when this file will be imported you will be able to give this default export any name, e.g. `import defaultExportAlias from "module-name";`

Comment: I updated my post and am showing the entire code. I don't understand how importing runs that line of code since the entire code in the module is assigned to a variable, which includes stuff outside of the function. So it isn't clear how the function can be called using an import.

Comment: File that you uploaded does not call mentioned anonymous function at any time. There must be another file that imports this one. If its part of a project, search for name of the file where this function is located and see where it gets imported.

Comment: But even if it gets imported, how could it possibly even be assigned to any variable since the entire module contains code outside of the function?

Comment: There are many ways of importing, if a file is using syntax as in my response, only default export will be assigned to the variable ("defaultExportAlias" in this case), since anon function is default export in this case, it will be assigned to the variable and can be called by adding parenthesis at the end defaultExportAlias(). Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Your answer looks correct, but I scanned the project and couldn't find any import. It's a Nodejs app, so maybe something else is going on in some other module.

Comment: No there isn't anything else going on in the code. Please read the entire documentation I've linked above, there are multiple ways to import code, answers here introduce only few of the ways.

Comment: Try adding console.trace() to the anon function, start project and look where its being called

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import func from './file';

func();
```

However keep in mind that unnamed exports are a violation of [this eslint rule](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.27.5/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md).

Comment: I updated my post to show the entire code. So according to your suggestion, is that even allowed?

Comment: It's allowed. Linter rules are arbitrary limitations devs impose on themselves but not rules about the language itself.

Comment: I scanned the project, but couldn't find anything with func();

Comment: `I scanned the project, but couldn't find anything with func();` Of course you didn't, it'll very likely have another name...